# Visual basic list box

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am trying to get each item in a list box into a string array. However, I keep getting an index error and I am not sure why. I am doing this so i can perform a LINQ on the array. Here is the error and the code in question. Thank you for any help in advance.

Error:
InvalidArgument=Value of '16' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Code:

```
    Dim size As Integer = lstBoxSeats.Items.Count()
    Dim seats(size) As String

    For i = 0 To size
        seats(i) = lstBoxSeats.Items(i).ToString()
    Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array is zero based, the count is actual number of items. You need to subtract 1 from the count for your index.

i.e.

**Correction:**  just realized that you were using count to dimension your seats array which is leaving a empty position in your seats array

```
Dim size As Integer = lstBoxSeats.Items.Count()-1  'Subtract 1 here instead of in the For statement
Dim seats(size) As String 

For i = 0 To size 
    seats(i) = lstBoxSeats.Items(i).ToString() 
Next
```

Comment: That worked thank you. With my LINQ i get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error. I will check your answer as correct when it allows me to. Thank you.

Comment: @amedeiros You are welcome, see if the correction that I made makes any difference

Comment: I'd suggest you name the variable "last" instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because index is zero based i.e starts from 0 while Count is the amount of items which starts from 1, so if there are 16 items it means that maximum index is 15 (0-15) and count is 16(1-16)